# How to TypeError for Electron App Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im kind of new to JavaScript and I can't find the issue of the error which im receiving with "document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "Success!" as I receive a TypeError stating "document.getElementById" is not a function. I want it to read the HTML page input of the password being entered from 'index.html'. The current script is the Electron App Constructor.

```
var document = ('index.html')


let win;

app.on('ready', () => {
let main = null
let loading = new BrowserWindow({width:400, height:300, frame:false, icon: __dirname + '/assets/Icon.png'})

loading.once('show', () => {
    main = new BrowserWindow({width:1800, height:800, minWidth:1600, minHeight:600, webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }, frame: false, icon: __dirname + '/assets/Icon.png', show: false })
    main.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
        loading.show();
            password = document.getElementById("license").value;
            if(password == '12345'){
              document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "Success!"
              main.show();
            } else{
              document.getElementById("login").innerHTML = "Wrong password!";
              app.quit();
            }
    })
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the first line
var document = ('index.html')

And check.
Since document is set by browser.
And it is not a good practice to override it

Comment: "document is not defined"

Comment: Can you share live demo?